# Failure of Surface Area by Cylindrical Shells

Tags: calculus

In my Calculus class, we learned about finding the surface area of a surface of revolution by using frustum shells, and we derived the formula

$$
S = \int_{a}^{b}{2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}} \mathrm{d}x
$$

To me, it makes sense to approximate the surface area using cylindrical shells instead.  My teacher mentioned that cylindrical shells don't work.  Why is this?

Comment: The smaller $f'(x)$ is the greater the degree that cylindrical shells will underestimate the surface area.

Consider the degenerate case of a disk.

i.e. the function $y = 0$ rotated around the $x$ axis bound by $x = 0$, and $x = 1$

What is the side wall of the cylindrical shell?  It is 0.

Comment: Isn't the effect of a small $f'(x)$ taken care of by the fact that the integral uses "infinitesimally small" intervals?

Comment: Each shell underestimates the surface area by the same scaling factor $(\sqrt {1 + \frac {dy}{dx}}).$  And cutting the shells smaller may make for a small error per shell.  But since every shell is an underestimate, when you integrate them all, you will have underestimated your surface area.

Comment: Forget “infinitesimals.” You’re approximating the surface area via some small, but finite mesh. For the approximation to be valid and give you the correct surface area, the error in the approximation has to get small “fast enough” as the mesh gets finer. That doesn’t happen with your approximation, as Doug M has pointed out. Essentially, you’re making the same error as in the fallacious proofs that $\pi=2$ or $\sqrt2=2$. In case you haven’t seen those before, there a video [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jUeIjZI32Jg).

Comment: @amd thanks for the comment.  I guess the part that "clicked" for me was that 'the error in the approximation has to get small “fast enough” as the mesh gets finer.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, cylindrical shells fail for the same reason that the “proofs” that $\pi=2$ or $\sqrt2=2$ do: the error doesn’t get small “fast enough.” (If you haven’t seen those fallacious proofs before, you can find a video presentation [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jUeIjZI32Jg).) You’re approximating the surface area with a Riemann sum. For it to converge to the true value, the error in this approximation has to get small “fast enough” as the mesh gets smaller. For the stairstep approximations in the false proofs I cited, not only does the error not get small, but it remains constant. Using cylindrical shells to compute the surface area involves a similar stairstep construction. I haven’t worked through this specific case, so the error in this approximation might well remain constant, too, but at any rate is doesn’t get small fast enough to make for a valid approximation to the surface area.